# How to show Type name in Twig

Tags: symfony, twig

I have 2 tables: *Product* and *Type*. Relationship is One *Type* has Many *Product*

```
Type:    id, name
Product: id, name, type_id
```

I dont know how to show type name in Twig, I'm new in Symfony and here is my code:

```
<div>
    {% for pro in product %}
        <div>Product name: {{ pro.name }}</div>
        <div>
            Type name:
        </div>
        <div>Price: {{ pro.price }}</div>
        <div>
            {% for img in pro.images %}
                <img src="{{ "/uploads/product/" ~ img.path }}" style="height: 100px;">
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can access the properties of an object in Twig. You should not look at your database, but the way your entities are made. Your *Product* has a `$id`, `$name` and `$type`. *Type* has `$id` and `$name`.

- In Twig you can do `{{product.name}}`
- To get the type, you want `{{product.type}}`
- To get the name of the type, you want `{{product.type.name}}`

So, in your code, that would be:

```
<div>
    Type name: {{ pro.type.name }} 
</div>
```

---

Internally, the Twig parser will get `$product` and check if it has the method `getName()` when you do `{{product.name}}`. That same logic applies to `{{product.type.name}}`. It checks if `$product` has `getType()`, then if that has `getName()`. The PHP equivalant is `$product->getType()->getName()`.

You almost never should type an actual method in your code. If you have to, you might want to take a step back and re-evaluate, because it often is a [code smell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell).

Answer (score 2):

You can just add {{ pro.type.name }} to your code:

```
<div>
    {% for pro in product %}
        <div>Product name: {{ pro.name }}</div>
        <div>
            Type name: {{ pro.type.name }}
        </div>
        <div>Price: {{ pro.price }}</div>
        <div>
            {% for img in pro.images %}
                <img src="{{ "/uploads/product/" ~ img.path }}" style="height: 100px;">
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

And be sure that type attribute refer to Type entity. Your product entity should have type attribute like below:

```
/**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Type", inversedBy="products")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $type;

 // getter

public function getType()
    {
        return $this->type;
    }
```

And your Type entity should have products attribute like below:

```
/**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Type", mappedBy="type")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=true)
     */
    private $products;

public function getProducts()
    {
        return $this->products;
    }
```

Comment: It would be even better to use `pro.type.name`

Comment: I got this error: Neither the property "product_type" nor one of the methods "product_type()", "getproduct_type()"/"isproduct_type()"/"hasproduct_type()" or "__call()" exist and have public access in class "App\Entity\Product".

Comment: /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\ProductType", inversedBy="type")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $type;

Comment: try to add getter and setter to your entities and make sure that Type entity has products attributes. I update my answer. Please let me know if it works.

Comment: replace inversedBy="type" with inversedBy="products"

Comment: my Type entity has type attribute too: /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Product", mappedBy="type")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $type;

Comment: I added getter and setter as well

Comment: The mappedBy value should not have the same name as the attribute name: /** * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Product", mappedBy="other_name") * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false) */ private $type;